# failed upgrading ioncube loeader for php 7.0 and 7.1 in plesk

Tags: php, apache, plesk, whmcs

I have installed **plesk onyx** in my ubuntu server plus **php v7.0 and v7.1**. When I tried to install **WHCMS v 7.3.0** he told me that I have old ioncube loeader version and I need to make an upgrade to continue the installation so I followed that tutorial : https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/214527125-The-IonCube-loader-is-not-available-for-Plesk-PHP-7-1 
and this is the version of php v7.0 and v7.1 :

```
root@sd-86418:/opt/plesk/php/7.1/lib/php/modules# /opt/plesk/php/7.1/bin/php -v

PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2017 15:42:12) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.1.10, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies


root@sd-86418:/opt/plesk/php/7.1/lib/php/modules# /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -v

Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was already loaded
PHP 7.0.24 (cli) (built: Sep 29 2017 12:33:10) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader (enabled) + Intrusion Protection from ioncube24.com (unconfigured) v10.0.3, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by ionCube Ltd.
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.24, Copyright (c) 1999-2017, by Zend Technologies
```

The issue is all time I got **HTTP ERROR 500**. Please any one help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Cannot load the ionCube PHP Loader - it was already loaded

In Plesk ioncube module is already installed and loaded out of the box with the corresponding plesk-php70-ioncube-loader package. You shouldn't install it as described in the mentioned KB article.

Actually, it is a bad idea to install WHMCS on the server where Plesk is already installed. Consequences may be unpredictable. Anyway, why do you think that WHMCS installer uses Plesk PHP /opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php instead of OS vendor's PHP from /usr/bin/php with own outdated ioncubeloader?

Comment: thanks for replay. well i fixed by downgrade the version of php to v5.6 but i still have the same issue with crontabe so i don't get any updates because of that error.